# Being Careful with open sets

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

I have a function $f$ on [$0,1$]. I don't know whether on not it will be continuous at $1$ but I know if you pick any $0<\eta<1$  then it will be continuous on [$0,\eta$]. Surely this is enough to say $f$ is continuous on [$0,1$). If so why is this justified and rigorous. If not why not?

Comment: Continuity is a local property, and every $x\in [0,1)$ has a neighbourhood that is contained in some $[0,\eta]$.

Comment: For any sequence in [0,1) converging to some point of [0,1), the sequence is eventually in some [0,c] for c close to 1.

Comment: @ Daniel Fischer                                                                                                                                        Is this something which is true only because of the properties of continuity. If you had a statement A which was true for all [$0,\eta$]. Would  statement A be true on [0,1). This statement A could be anything you like- I just want to know if its because continuity is special in that it's a local property which makes it true for this question.

Comment: You can't say the same about _uniform_ continuity, though. (Example: $f(x)=\begin{cases}\frac1{1-x}&x\ne1\\0&x=1\end{cases}$ is uniformly continuous on every $[0,\eta]$ but not $[0,1)$. It is _continuous_ on $[0,1)$, just not uniformly so.) EDIT: The same example works with boundedness.

Comment: @ columbus8myhw thanks

Comment: @Arcane1729 Note that continuity is a property of the point $x$; $f$ is continuous on a set $A$ iff it's continuous on every point in $A$. _Uniform_ continuity and boundedness are properties of the set $A$.

Comment: For continuous functions on compact sets — i.e. closed and bounded, like $[a,b]$ — the ideas begin to overlap. Note that a function is always bounded at a point — what would it mean for something to be unbounded at a point? — and we have that a continuous function is bounded on any compact set. Similarly, any continuous function is also uniformly continuous on any compact set. Compact sets are nice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is justified. Indeed, $f$ is continuous on $[0, 1)$ iff for every $x \in [0, 1)$ and for every $\epsilon$, there is $\delta$ such that for all $y$ with $|y-x| < \delta$, $|f(y) - f(x)| < \epsilon$. This condition is true: pick $\eta = \frac{1+x}{2}$ and use that it is continuous on $[0, \eta]$.